# R: how to total the number of NA in each col of data.frame

Tags: r

To calculate the number of NAs in the entire data.frame, I can use `sum(is.na(df)`, however, how can I count the number of NA in each column of a big data.frame? I tried `apply(df, 2, function (x) sum(is.na(df$x))` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Try removing 'df$' in df$x.

Comment: @AndreyShabalin please post this as an answer (add some code, e.g. `x <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, NA, NA, 1), b = c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA));apply(x, 2, function(z) sum(is.na(z)))
`).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could try:

```
colSums(is.na(df))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 
#   2  4  2  4  4
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:4), 5*20,replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Answer (score 14):

Since the `dplyr::summarise_all` function has been [superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) by using `across` inside the original function and `dplyr::funs` has been deprecated, the current tidyverse approach would probably be something like:

```
df %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.x))))
```

Answer (score 13):

With `dplyr`...

```
df %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
```

or using the `purrr` library

```
map(df, ~sum(is.na(.)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sapply` :

```
sapply(X = df, FUN = function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following functions

1. Using colSums()

   `colSums(is.na(df))`
2. Using apply()

   `apply(df, 2, function(x) {sum(is.na(x))})`
3. Using a function

   `sum.na <- function (x) {`
   `sum(is.na(x))`
   `}`

   `print(sum.na(df))`
4. Using lapply()

   `lapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`
5. Using sapply()

   `lapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`

Answer (score 2):

To maintain the names of each column, use this variation (substitute name of dataframe for df in example):

```
apply(is.na(df), 2, sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) length(which(is.na(x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the `dplyr` function to achieve this outcome:

```
df %>%
  select(everything()) %>%  
  summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
```

The above solution allows you to select specific columns by replacing the `everything()` with specific columns you are interested in analysing. This can be useful to meet specific needs. If you want to read further, you can check this page https://sebastiansauer.github.io/sum-isna/.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
apply(is.na(df), 2, sum)
```

this will return total sum of NAs available in each column

example

```
df <- data.frame(x= as.numeric(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,'fg',8,8,3,4,2)),
                 y = as.numeric(c(1,2,3,4,5,'as',7,8,9,9,1,4,2)),
                 z = as.numeric(c(1,4,6,7,'a',12,45,7,'as',1,23,12,'la')))


apply(is.na(df), 2, sum)
```

output

```
x y z 
1 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
egdf = data.frame(x=c(1, 10, NA, NA, 2), y=c(2.4, NA, 2, 3.5, NA))
setDT(egdf)      # make it a data.table
egdf[, z := x+y] # add another column
# use .SDcols after 2nd ',' to specify only some columns
egdf[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {return(sum(is.na(x)))}) ,]
###
#    x y z
# 1: 2 2 4
```

Comment: This seems separate from my previous answer, but if I should rather add this to that, let me know, please & I will.

Answer (score 0):

Another, very simple, approach is just to use the summary() function on the dataframe. It will give at a glance the NA counts for each column.

From [this website (intro2r)](https://intro2r.com/summarising-data-frames.html) on the summary() function, "If a variable contains missing data then the number of NA values is also reported." (Note, I could not find confirmation in the official docs.)

A downside to summary() is it gets more involved if you want to extract the NA counts for use in another context. Though there are ways to parse a summary() object, for example, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520350/convert-summary-to-data-frame).