# R - summary with multiple criterions in dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of models which is called `list_RLM`

I am using the caret package to compare the results. I used :

```
res = resamples(list_RLM)
```

And I have the summary :

```
> summary(res)

Call:
summary.resamples(object = res)

Models: Model1, Model2, Model3 
Number of resamples: 10 

MAE 
       Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. NA's
Model1 3.588910 5.218382 6.048223 5.867826 6.641718 7.089557    0
Model2 5.821488 6.083818 6.235782 6.533820 7.092455 7.651828    0
Model3 5.718588 6.373973 7.076648 6.936426 7.471962 7.809910    0

RMSE 
       Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
Model1 4.670845 5.954618 6.839484 6.800493 7.746462  8.310253    0
Model2 7.205834 7.854358 8.670934 8.735472 9.080558 10.906001    0
Model3 6.900938 7.758733 8.578707 8.855764 9.875752 11.116252    0

Rsquared 
        Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. NA's
Model1 0.9339040 0.9438636 0.9551666 0.9555496 0.9686839 0.9786888    0
Model2 0.9914923 0.9920507 0.9935229 0.9932357 0.9941703 0.9948047    0
Model3 0.9873668 0.9901259 0.9919001 0.9916127 0.9933167 0.9950883    0
```

And I want 3 dataframes.

One called MAE with the following informations :

```
       Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. NA's
       3.588910 5.218382 6.048223 5.867826 6.641718 7.089557    0
       .821488 6.083818 6.235782 6.533820 7.092455 7.651828    0
       5.718588 6.373973 7.076648 6.936426 7.471962 7.809910    0
```

And the same thing for `RMSE` and `Rsquared`

Do you know what can I do ?

I tried for the post : [R - convert summary to data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520350/r-convert-summary-to-data-frame)

```
data.frame(unclass(summary(res)), check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

But it gave me the following error :

```
Error in summary.resamples(object = res) : 
  could not find function "summary.resamples"
```

Comment: When you call `summary(res)` here, you are implicitly calling `print.a(summary.b(res))`, where 'b' is the class of `res` and 'a' is the class of the object returned by `summary(res)`.  `summary(res)` must be some sort of data object, most likely a list of things. `print.a` is then some specialised print function for that type of objects. Try saving the returned object, and inspect it, as in `s <- summary(res); str(s)`. You might be able to deduce which elements in `s` to extract.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you :)

Comment: I suggest you mark helpful comments, and paste the solution as an answer or modify your question to include the answer.