# Convert model summary to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lm, summary

I was reading this post : [Convert summary to data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520350/convert-summary-to-data-frame) about converting summary to data frames. However I'm not sure how to do it for model summary i.e. :

```
set.seed(42)
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- rexp(100)
model <- lm(y ~ x)
```

**Trying to use code in post**

```
data.frame(unclass(summary(model)), check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However I see error :

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'x'
```

Is there any simple way how can I convert this ?

Comment: An alternative is to use `tidy` from the `broom` package, i.e. `tidy(model)`.

Comment: If you want to get some more aggregate stats you could also use `glance(model)` from the broom package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
model_df <- as.data.frame(coef(summary(model)))

#               Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)  0.2308795 0.15761451  1.464836 0.14616637
# x           -0.1645842 0.09883217 -1.665290 0.09904877
```

To avoid the row names you could add them in as column afterwards or directly with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
model_df <- data.table(coef(summary(model)), keep.rownames = 'term')
setDF(model_df)

#          term   Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
# 1 (Intercept)  0.2308795 0.15761451  1.464836 0.14616637
# 2           x -0.1645842 0.09883217 -1.665290 0.09904877
```

EDIT: As commented but deschen, the column names won't be pretty to fix the column names you could use `setNames()`.

```
model_df <- 
  setNames(model_df, c("term", "coef", "std_error", "t_value", "p_value"))
#          term       coef  std_error   t_value    p_value
# 1 (Intercept)  0.2308795 0.15761451  1.464836 0.14616637
# 2           x -0.1645842 0.09883217 -1.665290 0.09904877
```

Comment: However, going the way through coef leads to invalid column names (i.e. containing spaces or other special characters).