# Convert summary of data.frame into a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, type-conversion, summary

How can I convert the summary run on a data.frame into a data.frame itself? I need a data.frame as an output to knitr::kable in RMarkdown.

In particular I have this dataframe

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6))
ds <- summary(d)
class(ds)
# returns "table"
```

And I need `ds` in a `data.frame` format.

The output I would like would be a `data.frame` with "Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", etc. as row names, "a" and "b" as column names, and the numbers in the cells.

`as.data.frame` doesn't work:

```
ds.df <- as.data.frame(ds)
print(ds.df)
# Output is messed up
```

The code in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520350/convert-summary-to-data-frame) doesn't work either:

```
df.df2 <- data.frame(unclass(summary(ds.df)), check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(df.df2)
# Output equally messed up
```

`broom::tidy` on a table is deprecated and in anyway returns an error:

```
df.df3 <- broom::tidy(ds)
# Returns error
# Error: Columns 1 and 2 must be named.
# Moreover
# 'tidy.table' is deprecated.
```

The `as.data.frame.matrix` puts "Min" and the other names of the statistics inside each cell, instead of them being row names:

```
ds.df3 <- as.data.frame.matrix(ds)
print(ds.df3)
# Returns "Min" and "1sd Qu." inside the cell
# instead of them being row names
```

Comment: Well, the same answer from the post you linked to suggests `do.call(cbind, lapply(d, summary))` which seems to work for your case.

Comment: @RonakShah Yes but I have have preferred a real conversion of the object returned by `summary(df)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use the `matrix` route

```
out <- as.data.frame.matrix(ds)
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
out
             a             b
1 Min.   :1.0   Min.   :4.0  
2 1st Qu.:1.5   1st Qu.:4.5  
3 Median :2.0   Median :5.0  
4 Mean   :2.0   Mean   :5.0  
5 3rd Qu.:2.5   3rd Qu.:5.5  
6 Max.   :3.0   Max.   :6.0
```

---

If we need the `min` etc as row names, loop over the columns with `sapply` and apply the `summary`

```
as.data.frame(sapply(d, summary))
```

-output

```
          a   b
Min.    1.0 4.0
1st Qu. 1.5 4.5
Median  2.0 5.0
Mean    2.0 5.0
3rd Qu. 2.5 5.5
Max.    3.0 6.0
```

Comment: Exactly, that's not the output expected. I want "Min." as the row name, not inside the cell

Comment: @robertspierre i am not sure what format you needed the output.  I assumed that the long format is not what you wanted

Comment: I need "Min", "1st Qu." as row names, "a" and "b" as column names, and only the numbers in the cell

Comment: @robertspierre what about the updated post

Comment: yes that is working, although it's kind of circumventing it. It's not converting the table into the data.frame as I want it, but don't create the table in the first place. But I guess that's the most elegant way of doing it

Comment: @robertspierre have you checked the updated i.e. `as.data.frame(sapply(d, summary))`

Comment: If it solves your problem you're encouraged to accept it by clicking the check-mark ...