# Extracting data from R summary object to a table

Tags: r

With some df `tab1` that gives summary output like below

```
summary(tab1)
```

[image]

I need to extract a table out of this like below

[image]

What is the right way to go about extracting data for the above table ? Looking for a solution that can use R's `summary` object or equivalent. Eventually I will use `kabble` to pretty print it.

Comment: Does the link below help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520350/convert-summary-to-data-frame

Answer (score 1):

Here is another tidyverse approach. Just select the columns you want and iterate over them one at a time. This gives you a list of them that you can then join together.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

# add in a NA value
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2[5, "wt"] <- NA

# select variables of interest
# iterate over each column to create a data frame of the summary statistics
# move through the list joining the results together
# iterate through each joined column, replacing NA with 0
summary_vars <- mtcars2 %>% 
  select(wt, hp) %>% 
  imap(~ enframe(c(summary(.x)), name = "Metric", value = .y)) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "Metric") %>% 
  modify_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0) %>% 
  filter(Metric %in% c("Mean", "Min.", "Max.", "Median", "NA's"))

summary_vars
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   Metric     wt    hp
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Min.    1.51   52 
# 2 Median  3.22  123 
# 3 Mean    3.21  147.
# 4 Max.    5.42  335 
# 5 NA's    1       0
```

You can now use this `summary_vars` with `kable()`.

Answer (score 1):

We could combine `apply` with `kable_styling` from `kableExtra` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

#example data
df <- mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3)  


as.data.frame(apply(df,2,summary)) %>% 
  kbl() %>% 
  kable_styling()
```

[image]

Comment: And then, how can we save that dataframe into a table, for example in csv format?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will give you what you want:

```r
df <- data.frame(
    a = c(rnorm(100), NA),
    b = rnorm(101),
    c = rnorm(101)
)
sumtab <- summary(df)
rownames(sumtab) <- names(summary(df$a))
sumtab <- sumtab[c("Mean", "Min.", "Max.", "Median", "NA's"),]
sumtab[5,][is.na(sumtab[5,])] <- 0
knitr::kable(gsub("^.+\\:", "", sumtab))

|       |      a |      b  |      c |
|:------|:-------|:--------|:-------|
|Mean   |0.1033  |-0.03059 |-0.1172 |
|Min.   |-2.0331 |-2.63760 |-1.9736 |
|Max.   |1.9081  |1.93582  |2.1688  |
|Median |0.2622  |0.05986  |-0.1869 |
|NA's   |1       |0        |0       |
```

Alternatively, you could just select the rows that you want from the summary table when you initially calculate the summary and use your preferred names:

```r
sumtab <- summary(df)[c(4, 1, 6, 3, 7),]
rownames(sumtab) <- c("Mean", "Min", "Max", "Median", "NA")
sumtab["NA", ][is.na(sumtab["NA", ])] <- 0
knitr::kable(gsub("^.+\\:", "", sumtab))

|       |      a  |      b |      c  |
|:------|:--------|:-------|:--------|
|Mean   |-0.06337 |0.1074  |-0.00909 |
|Min    |-2.27831 |-1.9913 |-2.01234 |
|Max    |2.09241  |2.2401  |2.58487  |
|Median |-0.08660 |0.2212  |0.01049  |
|NA     |1        |0       |0        |
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on `purrr::map` and `data.table`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

mtcars2 <- mtcars; mtcars2[4,7] <- NA

mtcars2 %>% 
  map(summary) %>% bind_rows %>% transpose(keep.names = "rn") %>% 
  setnames(-1, names(mtcars2)) %>% as_tibble

#> # A tibble: 7 × 12
#>   rn        mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec     vs     am  gear  carb
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Min.     10.4  4     71.1  52    2.76  1.51  14.5  0      0      3     1   
#> 2 1st Qu.  15.4  4    121.   96.5  3.08  2.58  16.9  0      0      3     2   
#> 3 Median   19.2  6    196.  123    3.70  3.32  17.6  0      0      4     2   
#> 4 Mean     20.1  6.19 231.  147.   3.60  3.22  17.8  0.438  0.406  3.69  2.81
#> 5 3rd Qu.  22.8  8    326   180    3.92  3.61  18.8  1      1      4     4   
#> 6 Max.     33.9  8    472   335    4.93  5.42  22.9  1      1      5     8   
#> 7 NA's     NA   NA     NA    NA   NA    NA      1   NA     NA     NA    NA
```

---

A `tidyverse` approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars[4,7] <- NA

mtcars %>% 
  summary %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  separate(Freq, into = c("name", "value"),sep = ":") %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_trim(as.character(.))),
         value = parse_number(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "name", names_from = "Var2", values_from = "value") %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(name,"Qu."))

#> # A tibble: 5 × 12
#>   name     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec     vs     am  gear  carb
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Min.    10.4  4     71.1   52   2.76  1.51  14.5  0      0      3     1   
#> 2 Median  19.2  6    196.   123   3.70  3.32  17.6  0      0      4     2   
#> 3 Mean    20.1  6.19 231.   147.  3.60  3.22  17.8  0.438  0.406  3.69  2.81
#> 4 Max.    33.9  8    472    335   4.93  5.42  22.9  1      1      5     8   
#> 5 NA's    NA   NA     NA     NA  NA    NA      1   NA     NA     NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
# summary of numeric (including factor class) columns of a data frame
my_summ <- function(df) {

  df_nonchar <- df[, !sapply(df, typeof) %in% "character"]
  summ <- data.frame(summary(df_nonchar), row.names = NULL)

  # test for empty columns usually the 1st column is empty as a result of class
  # (summary obj) which is "table" to data.frame coercion.
  empty <- sapply(summ, function(x) all(x == ""))
  summ <- summ[, !empty]
  summ <- setNames(summ, c("var_name", "stats"))
  summ <- summ[which(!is.na(summ$stats)), ]

  # just in case if there are multiple :'s, we need to split only at the first match
  summ$stats <- sub(":", "-;-", summ$stats)
  summ <- data.frame(summ[1], do.call(rbind, strsplit(summ$stats, "-;-")))
  names(summ)[-1] <- c("stats", "value")

  # pivot into wide form, using 'stats' column as a key.
  summ <- reshape(summ,
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = "var_name",
    timevar = "stats",
    v.names = "value"
  )

  var_nms <- strsplit(colnames(summ)[-1], "value\\.")
  var_nms <- vapply(var_nms, function(x) x[[2]], NA_character_)
  var_nms <- gsub("\\s+$", "", var_nms) # remove white spaces
  names(summ)[-1] <- var_nms
  rownames(summ) <- NULL

  # remove white spaces
  summ <- as.data.frame(sapply(summ, function(x) gsub("\\s+$", "", x)))

  # when vars in the dataset contain NAs, we may have two additional columns in
  # summary call
  nas <- "NA's" %in% colnames(summ)
  if (any(nas)) {
    colnames(summ)[colnames(summ) == "NA's"] <- "missing"
  }
  summ
}
```

```r
my_summ(mtcars[, 1:5])
   var_name  Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu.  Max.
1       mpg 10.40   15.43  19.20 20.09   22.80 33.90
2       cyl 4.000   4.000  6.000 6.188   8.000 8.000
3      disp  71.1   120.8  196.3 230.7   326.0 472.0
4        hp  52.0    96.5  123.0 146.7   180.0 335.0
5      drat 2.760   3.080  3.695 3.597   3.920 4.930

# transpose of that would put stats(summaries) on rows and vars on columns
t(my_summ(mtcars[, 1:5]))
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]       
var_name "     mpg" "     cyl" "     disp" "      hp" "     drat"
Min.     "10.40"    "4.000"    " 71.1"     " 52.0"    "2.760"    
1st Qu.  "15.43"    "4.000"    "120.8"     " 96.5"    "3.080"    
Median   "19.20"    "6.000"    "196.3"     "123.0"    "3.695"    
Mean     "20.09"    "6.188"    "230.7"     "146.7"    "3.597"    
3rd Qu.  "22.80"    "8.000"    "326.0"     "180.0"    "3.920"    
Max.     "33.90"    "8.000"    "472.0"     "335.0"    "4.930"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice package for it called vtable

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(rnorm(100), NA), b = rnorm(101), c = rnorm(101))

library(vtable)

# return will return the data as data.frame but look at other options as well
sumtable(df, out = "return") 

#   Variable   N   Mean Std. Dev.    Min Pctl. 25 Pctl. 75   Max
# 1        a 100  0.235     0.955 -1.593   -0.433    0.792 3.078
# 2        b 101  0.052     1.017 -2.542   -0.675    0.654 2.753
# 3        c 101 -0.163      1.01 -2.894   -0.832    0.497 2.326

# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vtable/vignettes/sumtable.html
# Options for out:
# browser:  Loads output in web browser.
# viewer:   Loads output in Viewer pane (RStudio only).
# htmlreturn:   Returns HTML code for output file.
# return:   Returns summary table in data frame format. Depending on options, the data frame may be entirely character variables.
# csv:  Returns summary table in data.frame format and, with a file option, saves that to CSV.
# kable:    Returns a knitr::kable()
# latex:    Returns a LaTeX table.
# latexpage:    Returns an independently-buildable LaTeX document.
```