# Extraction of a table from summary function

Tags: r, summary

I am working on R markdown. I have done a summary of the sheet and tried to extract it with the following code but the output does not make any sense.

```
    Library (tidyverse)
    Library (kableExtra)
    Library(knitr)

    library(readxl)
    ATT <- read_excel("E:/MY PROJECTS/OSTEOTOMY ACL/ATT.xlsx", 
        col_types = c("numeric", "text", "numeric", 
            "text", "numeric", "skip", "numeric", 
            "skip"))
    View(ATT)

    summary(ATT)
```

I get the following output

```
Flexion_Degrees Load_Direction         Load_N      Osteotomy_Type    
 Min.   :15      Length:30          Min.   : 18.0   Length:30         
 1st Qu.:30      Class :character   1st Qu.:100.0   Class :character  
 Median :30      Mode  :character   Median :134.0   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :39                         Mean   :179.3                     
 3rd Qu.:30                         3rd Qu.:206.8                     
 Max.   :90                         Max.   :400.0                     
                                    NA's   :4                         
  PTS_Degrees        ATT_ACL     
 Min.   :-0.900   Min.   :0.600  
 1st Qu.: 0.000   1st Qu.:2.400  
 Median : 8.000   Median :3.800  
 Mean   : 6.427   Mean   :3.736  
 3rd Qu.:10.000   3rd Qu.:5.200  
 Max.   :16.300   Max.   :6.700  
                  NA's   :1
```

I want to convert this output to a nice editable table. I searched and found the following code

```
    ATT_STATS_Table <- ATT 

    as.data.frame(apply(ATT_STATS_Table,2,summary)) %>% 
      kbl() %>% 
      kable_styling()
```

Unfortunately the output looks like this

```
Flexion_Degrees Load_Direction  Load_N  Osteotomy_Type  PTS_Degrees ATT_ACL
Length  30  30  30  30  30  30
Class   character   character   character   character   character   character
Mode    character   character   character   character   character
```

Can anyone help me how to sort that out?

```
ATT_STATS_Table <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Flexion_Degrees, ~Load_Direction,              ~Load_N,  ~Osteotomy_Type, ~PTS_Degrees, ~ATT_ACL,
  30,               "Anterior",                   134,      "Native",        0,            5.5,
  90,               "Anterior",                   134,      "Native",        0,            4,
  30,               "Anterior",                   134,      "AOWO",          5,            5.8,
  90,               "Anterior",                   134,      "AOWO",          5,            4,
  30,               "Anterior",                   134,      "AOWO",          10,           5.7,
  90,               "Anterior",                   134,      "AOWO",          10,           3.8,
  30,               "Anterior",                   134,      "AOWO",          15,           5.2,
  90,               "Anterior",                   134,      "AOWO",          15,           3.1,
  15,               "UNLOADED",                   18,       "Native",        8,            0.6,
  15,               "UNLOADED",                   18,       "AOWO",          12.1,         2.1,
  15,               "UNLOADED",                   18,       "AOWO",          16.3,         3.2,
  15,               "Anterior",                   18,       "Native",        8,            NA_real_,
  15,               "Anterior",                   108,      "AOWO",          12.1,         1.4,
  15,               "Anterior",                   209,      "AOWO",          16.3,         6.7,
  30,               "Axial_Compression",          400,      "ACWO",          9.9,          3.8,
  30,               "Axial_Compression",          400,      "ACWO",          0,            2.354,
  30,               "Axial_Compression",          400,      "ACWO",          9.9,          6.339,
  30,               "Axial_Compression",          400,      "ACWO",          0,            2.649,
  30,               "Axial_Compression",          200,      "Native",        10,           1.7,
  30,               "Axial_Compression",          400,      "Native",        10,           3.7,
  30,               "Axial_Compression",          200,      "ACWO",          0,            1,
  30,               "Axial_Compression",          400,      "ACWO",          0,            2.4,
  30,               "Anterior",                   NA_real_, "Native",        10,           4.6,
  30,               "Anterior_Axial compression", NA_real_, "Native",        10,           4.7,
  30,               "Anterior",                   NA_real_, "ACWO",          0,            5.7,
  30,               "Anterior_Axial compression", NA_real_, "ACWO",          0,            6,
  30,               "Anterior",                   100,      "LCWO",          -0.9,         5,
  30,               "Anterior",                   100,      "MOWO",          1,            3.03,
  90,               "Anterior",                   100,      "LCWO",          -0.9,         1.675,
  90,               "Anterior",                   100,      "MOWO",          1,            2.587,
)
```

Comment: There are some good answers to this question (including the one you tried) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63564203/12400385). The issue is that you have both numeric and character/text columns.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help. Among all the proposed answers, the following code sorted my problem: ATT_STATS_Table <- ATT %>%  
  select(PTS_Degrees,Flexion_Degrees,Load_N,ATT_ACL)  

as.data.frame(apply(ATT_STATS_Table,2,summary)) %>% 
  kbl() %>% 
  kable_styling()

Comment: However, 2 important things has to be fulfilled as per the answers you proposed: 1: only numeric columns. 2: No NAs included at all in any of the involved column