Using the results of summary() as values in R
When I use the summary() function in R, the result is table that shows descriptive statistics in a table format, but it uses text with numbers in a way I can't use the object
(https://i.sstatic.net/NTPWg.png)
desc_stat <- summary(data)

to generate a boxplot for example (I know that the boxplot function already calculates these values, it is just an example). How can I transform this table in a way I can use it? Or is there another function I can use for this?
I was expecting a table with the values on a separate column.

Try data.frame(sapply(mtcars, summary)), with your data maybe data.frame(sapply(data, summary)).

Potential duplicate found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520350/convert-summary-to-data-frame

@AndreWildberg
When I use the code you provided I get this error:
'Error in dimnames(x) <- dnx : 'dimnames' applied to non-array'
But reading trough the link you sent I solved my problem. Thanks!
