# Finding missing values

Tags: r

I have a couple of questions as I am new to this.

1. How can I read in data using `\-\-` to look for missing values?
2. How can I determine how many values are missing in each variable?
   I tried using the `summary` command and `is.na` but can't's seem to get it right.

Comment: Did you try to specify the `na.strings` argument of `read.csv`-family of functions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question as is, seeking tutorial and it's too broad so it is off topic. Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and also take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can check the [R documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/topics) for questions like this or try google; you'll be redirected to pages like [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com) and will find so many good tutorials and examples.

Comment: Also `data.table::fread(na.strings = c("all/the/nas/you/want")`  will let you import the csv with predetermined NA's

Comment: For the counting part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273663/r-how-to-total-the-number-of-na-in-each-col-of-data-frame

Comment: I am trying to use "\-\-" as the string for missing values

Answer (score 0):

the first question is not clear, for the second one you can use

```
sapply(yourdataframe, function(x) sum(is.na(x))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273663/r-how-to-total-the-number-of-na-in-each-col-of-data-frame