# OOB values coming out as Null from Random Forest

Tags: r, random-forest, na

When I run random forest on dataset LLL

```
rfm <- randomForest(ONEorZERO~., data = LLL)
```

The code produces the following "Error in na.fail.default"

Even thou I take out the nulls (na.omit) and am not missing any values I still get the error.

I corrected the error as below and I get randomforest to successfully run.

```
rfm <- randomForest(ONEorZERO~., data = LLL, na.action = na.roughfix)
```

I can calculate the mean square error with the below code successfully:

```
rfm$mse
```

But when I try to calculate the OOB error with:

```
err <- rfm$err.rate[,1]
```

I get a Null value. Any idea why this could be? The data set has no na's or missing values so I can't figure out why it is not running?

here is some additional information
dputhead

> dput(head(LLL))

```
structure(list(AD_TAD_2NGEN = c(-4L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L), 
GGONWG_1NGEN = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), GI_TGI_4NGEN = c(193L, 
198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 200L), HUNQHN_2NGEN = c(-3L, -2L, 
-4L, -3L, -2L, -4L), ISHTDB_1NGEN = c(181L, 186L, 187L, 189L, 
185L, 186L), MP_VMP_3NGEN = c(105L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 110L, 
110L), PB14 = c(40L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 41L, 42L), PB16 = c(23L, 
23L, 23L, 22L, 24L, 24L), SH_SWO_4NGEN = c(99L, 102L, 101L, 
101L, 100L, 100L), TB_QTB_3NGEN = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), TY_UTY_1NGEN = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Osecond = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ONEorZERO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000111ef0>)
```

The full error message is below so it may have something to do with the format above?

> rfm <- randomForest(ONEorZERO~., data = LLL)
>   Error in na.fail.default(list(ONEorZERO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  : 
>     missing values in object

Comment: Thanks. Here is some additional (dputhead)

Comment: Clearly R is saying column `LLL$ONEorZERO` does contain NAs. Show us `colSums(is.na(df))` and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273663/r-how-to-total-the-number-of-na-in-each-col-of-data-frame).
Try building a model on only the first N rows to narrow down where the NAs are: `rfm <- randomForest(ONEorZERO ~ ., data = LLL[1:10])`. If all else fails, increase N in steps until you locate the NAs.

Comment: I have tried this "LLL[LLL$column == ''na",] for all the columns and it came back with 0 rows. I tried the suggested code and it gave me "The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?"

Comment: @Gary, no that's wrong. NA is a special value in R, not a string "na". You detect NA values with `is.na()` like I posted above, or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273663/r-how-to-total-the-number-of-na-in-each-col-of-data-frame). Please post us `colSums(is.na(LLL))` already. And if trying 5 rows was too small, then try say 20 or 100.

Comment: Your right. Thanks for the help. This has resolved that error. However the original issue remains, when I run "rfm$err.rate[,1]" I still get a null value. I do get this warning message when I run the random forest code. which may have something to do with it?  "Warning message:
In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?